# WordPress: Add a hashtag to the category-slugname

Tags: wordpress, hashtag, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to find a solution to **remove** e.g. `http://website/drinks/`, then **add** a hashtag at the beginning of the categories-slugname e.g. `#coffee`.

Current situation:

```
<ul>
<li class="cat-item-1"><a href="http://website/drinks/coffee/">Coffee</a></li>
<li class="cat-item-2"><a href="http://website/drinks/tea/">Tea</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Desired situation:**

```
<ul>
<li class="cat-item-1"><a href="#coffee">Coffee</a></li>
<li class="cat-item-2"><a href="#tea">Tea</a></li>
</ul>
```

The solution must be codded in functions.php of my WordPress theme. I'm not a master at coding, but I've founded a way to add a hash at the ending of the URL.

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'filter_categories', 10, 2);

function filter_categories($output, $args=array()){
      return preg_replace('/(\<a\shref=\"?[^\>]+?)\"/', '$1#"', $output);
}
```

Output:

```
<ul>
<li class="cat-item-1"><a href="http://website/drinks/coffee/#">Coffee</a></li>
<li class="cat-item-2"><a href="http://website/drinks/tea/#">tea</a></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately this is for away from my desired situation... Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', function($html, $args) {

    $pattern = '/https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?/';

    $html = preg_replace($pattern, '#', $html);

    return preg_replace('/\/["\']/', '"', $html);

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Wow thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for! :)